# Случайный выбор из набора чисел

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Извиняюсь облазил инет и не могу найти ответ как рандомно получить **одно из заданных чисел**. Например, я задал 1, 6, 11, 16, 21... и мне надо случайно одно из них. Помогите.

Comment: :)) улыбнула тема, помогите с рандомом. Хочется написать, что нет ничего на столько предсказуемого чем рандом :D
А если серьзено, закинь все цыфры в массив, а длину массива возьми в рандом, и по ячейкам читай что лежит в массиве.

Comment: >облазил инет и не могу найти ответ

[плохо лазили](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=javascript случайный элемент массива)

Comment: На собеседовании "Мне насрать, умеешь ты кодить или нет, гуглить умеешь? - Да! - Все берем тебя на работу"

Comment: @Bimawa, аналогично: "Насрать, что ты не знаешь элементарных вещей, на хэшкоде спросить умеешь? Берём!"

Comment: То есть вы не знаете, как найти случайный индекс? То есть случайное число от нуля до к-ва элементов в массиве минус 1?

Comment: Выбор любого элемента равновероятен? 

Или, например, из `[1,96,97,98,99,100]` вероятнее выпадет 1 или 96, чем остальные, т.к. случайность равномерно "ложится" на весь диапазон от `min` (1) до `max` (100), и потом берётся ближайшее число из разрешенных? В какой-то практической задаче недавно сталкивался с такой необходимостью.

Comment: Это потому, что для решения задачи надо не только гуглить, а еще и думать, и код писать.

Answer (score 4):

**JavaScript**:

```
var arr = new Array(100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108); //некий массив чисел
var RandElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length))]; //выбор рандомного элемента
```

**C#**

Предположим, что в int[] Array, длина которого N, содержатся все эти числа, которые Вам нужны.

Тогда с помощью такого кода можно получить рандомное из них:

```
int[] Array = new int[N]; //Тут содержатся все Ваши числа, их кол-во N

Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Seconds); //генератор (псевдо)рандомных чисел
//Аргемент конструктора Random может принимать любое целочисленное значение

int RandomNumber = Array[rnd.Next(0, N)]; //Получим рандомный элемент из массива Array
```

Comment: стоит же js тэг, при чем здесь c# ?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил сразу

Comment: Добавил javascript