# Динамическое добавление случайной картинки

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Я новичок в JavaScript, долго рылся в интернете и не смог найти примера реализации такой задачи!

1. Есть список картинок, их 8 шт:

   ```
   var img = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
   ```

   Выводятся они на сайте (мини галерея)
2. при нажатии на кнопку *добавить кратинку*, добавляется случайная картинка из этих 8.

Подскажите куда рыть, может есть какой пример.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Случайный выбор из набора чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192729/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb)

Answer (score 1):

Решается это следующим способом:

```
function addImgRnd(arr) {
    arr = arr || false;
    arr && (arr = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
    if(arr) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.scr='img/'+arr+'.jpg';
        document.getElementById('items').appendChild(img);
    }
}
```

В функцию передаем массив:

```
addImgRnd([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
```

Можно сделать авто-геренацию (заполнение массива, конкретной длиной - этим, как - бы, сможем принимать некий размер массива к примеру от сервера и генерировать на клиенте):

```
var len = 8;
addImgRnd(!function () {
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 1; len + 1 > i; ++i) {
      arr.push(i);
   }
   return arr;
}());
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как реализовать добавление картинки?

Comment: @ntym, "долго рылся в интернете и не смог найти примера реализациия такой задачи" ... половину задачи вам уже решили, осталась вторая которая даже не задача, а основа языка ... Вы на Ответ@mail.ru что ли искали решение задачи?

Comment: простите, данным сервисом не пользуюсь =)

Answer (score 1):

А добавление картинки можно реализовать, например, так:

```js
var pics = [
'https://wylsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/0eb1bd378967ec.jpg',
'https://rusargument.ru/data/photo/010316_052435261267.jpg',
'http://www.car-mania.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/2015-hyundai-santa-cruz-crossover-truck-concept-pickup.jpg',
'http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2015-11/1447857139_00.jpg',
'http://ustroistvo-avtomobilya.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Avtomobil-Fiat-FCC4-v-sinem-tsvete.jpg',
'http://avtomobil.az/data/preview/news/5/img4130156/sportivniy-kontcept-ot-nissan-prevratili-na-novuyu-nissan-maxima-2015.jpg',
'https://suvcar.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/JMC-predstavil-v-SHanhae-sumasshedshij-kontsept-Yuhu-01.jpg',
'http://chert-poberi.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/proga/111/zhenevskij_avtosalon-2016-11.jpg'
];

$('#changepic').click(function(){
  $('#picwrap').css('background-image', 'url('+pics[Math.floor(Math.random()*pics.length)]+')');
});
```

```css
#picwrap {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px black;
  background-image: url('https://wylsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/0eb1bd378967ec.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="picwrap"></div>
<br />
<button id="changepic">Сменить картинку</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: возможно я не правильно объяснил задачу, есть два кода, который дали вы, и который я нашел:
1. Случайный вывод 
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
arr = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
console.log(arr); // 3

2. создание новой картинки
function AddItem() {
    var newimg=document.createElement("img");
    newimg.setAttribute("src","images/loading.gif");
    document.getElementById("items").appendChild(newimg);
    }

Как мне теперь организовать так, что бы вместо images/loading.gif, получать **arr ** ???

Comment: @ntym, Вы никакой код кроме примера массива в вопросе не привели

Comment: видимо он решает задачи на чистом `js`, без использования `jquery` и сторонних библиотек, а вы предложили подключить целую либу, на одну задачу. многое можно решить без `jquery` - к тому-же, метки нет по `jquery`.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде разобрался, вот что получилось

```js
    function AddItem() {
        var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
        arr = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        var newimg=document.createElement("img");
        newimg.setAttribute("src","img/"+arr+".jpg");
        document.getElementById("items").appendChild(newimg);
    }
```

```css
div img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="items"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add Img" onClick="AddItem()">
```

Comment: Поправил ответ.